# Create a form within a new Desktop using CreateDesktop/SwitchDesktop

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi

I need to create a system modal form for an utility that should block the entire windows until certain values are entered. So I'm experimenting with creating desktops and switching. So far, creating a desktop switching to it, and going back works fine for me.

But, **when I try to create a form, from within a new thread, the form does not show up but the application keeps in the newly created blank desktop, therefore blocking the screen forever until I logoff.**

I made it based in the code found here:

http://developex.com/blog/system-modal-back/

```
// ScreenLocker.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

namespace Developex
{
   public ref class ScreenLocker
   {
   private:
      String ^_desktopName;
      Form ^_form;
      void DialogThread(void);

   public:
      static void ShowSystemModalDialog (String ^desktopName, Form ^form);
   };
}


// ScreenLocker.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ScreenLocker.h"

using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace Developex
{
   void ScreenLocker::DialogThread()
   {
      // Save the handle to the current desktop
      HDESK hDeskOld = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

      // Create a new desktop
      IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(_desktopName);
      HDESK hDesk = CreateDesktop((LPCWSTR)ptr.ToPointer(),
         NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
       Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);

      // Switch to the new deskop
      SwitchDesktop(hDesk);

      // Assign new desktop to the current thread
      SetThreadDesktop(hDesk);

      // Run the dialog
      Application::Run(_form);

      // Switch back to the initial desktop
      SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);
      CloseDesktop(hDesk);
   }

   void ScreenLocker::ShowSystemModalDialog(String ^desktopName, Form ^form)
   {
     // Create and init ScreenLocker instance
      ScreenLocker ^locker = gcnew ScreenLocker();
      locker->_desktopName = desktopName;
      locker->_form = form;

      // Create a new thread for the dialog
      (gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(locker,
         &Developex::ScreenLocker::DialogThread)))->Start();
   }
}
```

Well, now I'm trying to "translate" that to Delphi and so far this is what I have:

```
unit Utils;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, SyncObjs, ShellApi,
  AddTimeU;

type
  TFormShowThread = class(TThread)
    HDesktopglobal: HDESK;
    hDeskOld: HDESK;

    UHeapSize: ULong;
    tempDword: DWORD;

    frm : TfrmBlockScreen;
  private
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(form : TfrmBlockScreen);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TFormShowThread.Create(form : TfrmBlockScreen);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(True);
  frm := form;
end;


destructor TFormShowThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFormShowThread.Execute;
begin
    hDeskOld := GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    HDesktopglobal := CreateDesktop('Z', nil, nil, 0, GENERIC_ALL, nil);

    SwitchDesktop(HDesktopglobal);
    SetThreadDesktop(HDesktopglobal);

    // tried this
    Application.CreateForm(TfrmBlockScreen, frm);

    // also tried this with same result
    //frm := TfrmBlockScreen.Create(nil);
    //frm.Show();

    SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);

    CloseDesktop(HDesktopglobal);
end;

end.
```

I'm running that with this code:

```
var
  frmBlockScreen : TfrmBlockScreen;
  frmShowThread : TFormShowThread;
begin

  frmShowThread := TFormShowThread.Create(frmBlockScreen);
  frmShowThread.Priority := tpNormal;
  frmShowThread.OnTerminate := ThreadDone;
  frmShowThread.Start();
```

I don't understand why this does not work and the C++, supposedly should work, it creates a new form within the same application.

**This is how I ended doing it:**

I moved the form that I wanted to show, to a new project and compiled it as timeup.exe.
I created a process with the procedure shown below, sending the Desktop as parameter so I can assign the process to that desktop.
This way I didn't even needed to create a new thread... it's working so far.

**Is there any flaw in this?**

```
var
  HDesktopglobal: HDESK;
  hDeskOld: HDESK;

  sDesktopName : String;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  try
    hDeskOld := GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    sDesktopName := 'TimeUpDesktop';

    HDesktopglobal := CreateDesktop(PWideChar(sDesktopName), nil, nil, 0, GENERIC_ALL, nil);

    SwitchDesktop(HDesktopglobal);
    SetThreadDesktop(HDesktopglobal);

    ExecNewProcess('TimeUp.exe', sDesktopName);

    SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);
    CloseDesktop(HDesktopglobal);

  finally
    SwitchDesktop(hDeskOld);
    CloseDesktop(HDesktopglobal);
  end;

  Application.Run;
end.



procedure ExecNewProcess(ProgramName : String; Desktop : String);
var
  StartInfo  : TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo   : TProcessInformation;
  CreateOK   : Boolean;
begin

  { fill with known state }
  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartInfo.lpDesktop := PChar(Desktop);

  CreateOK := CreateProcess(PChar(ProgramName),nil, nil, nil,False,
              CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
              nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);

  { check to see if successful }
  if CreateOK then
    //may or may not be needed. Usually wait for child processes
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
end;
```

Comment: "this does not work" is very unhelpful.  It would be more helpful if we knew what it *does* do instead.

Comment: I explained in the first paragraph:  "the form does not show up but the application keeps in the newly created blank desktop, therefore blocking the screen forever until I logoff."

Comment: The problem is that the VCL is not thread safe, and you can't create a form in a secondary thread using `Application.CreateForm` the way you are. If you want to create and show a window from a thread other than the main (GUI) thread, you need to use API calls to do so. (See `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow` at MSDN to start off.)

Comment: Sounds malware for me. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa376875

Comment: Creating a new process and using IPC to communicate between the two sounds like the most robust design anyway, regardless of your problems with other approaches.  I've done similar things (though on the same desktop) and it works nicely - I was using named pipes for communication.  I'd recommend you stick with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go any further you need to recognise that the VCL design forces all VCL forms to be associated with the main GUI thread. You cannot create them on a different thread. So your design is fundamentally flawed in that way. You are never going to be able to create VCL forms in any thread other than the main GUI thread.

Even if that was not the case, your code could not do anything useful. That's because your thread does not contain a message loop. No sooner has the form been created, the thread which it is associated with terminates.

You could make this work with raw Win32 calls to `CreateWindow` etc. But you'd need at the very least to run a message loop in your thread for the lifetime of any windows created there.

As to why your code never switches back to the original desktop, I cannot be sure. Perhaps there is an exception in the code that attempts to create the form and so the code that restores the original desktop never runs. That code should be protected by a try/finally.

As a general point, in order to debug code which calls raw Win32 APIs, you must include error checking. You don't do any, and so you don't know which API call is failing. That would be the first step to debugging a problem like this, if we didn't already know that the approach is doomed to failure no matter what.

---

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it's not obvious to me why you are trying to run this form out of a different thread. Is there any reason why it cannot run out of the main GUI thread?

And to answer my own question, I am missing something. From the documentation of [`SetThreadDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250.aspx):

> The SetThreadDesktop function will fail if the calling thread has any windows or hooks on its current desktop (unless the hDesktop parameter is a handle to the current desktop).

Comment: Thanks, yes I know I'm missing the loop yet. But I wanted to try the code as I have it. Your main point is the real answer: the fact that VCL forms are associated with the main GUI thread only. So, if I want to show a "form", I guess I would need to create a single form application to be called by a CreateProcess call.... right?

Comment: Why do you need this form to be in a different thread or process? Why can't you run it out of the main GUI thread.

Comment: I made it on a thread to follow the C++ sample shown in the main question. It also made sense to me in order to "help" the form to show up in the other desktop, but after your explanation about which threads are the delphi Forms run at, it is clear to me it is not needed anyway. Actually, before I found the C++ code, I had that in the main thread, but I thought the creation of the dedicated thread would be the key to as why it wasn't working. But within the main thread or with a new thread, I kept getting the same results: just switch, form never appeared, and it never switched back.

Comment: OK, see my latest update. You do need a new thread so that this is the first window associated with that thread.

Comment: Thanks, David, so just to recap. 1) I keep my thread class 2) Manually create my form using CreateWindow

Comment: 3) Run a message loop.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, David, I redid the whole thing, I remembered I wasn't using a thread in the beginning, so I removed it and simplified the code. See my update in the question.

Comment: It looks basically sound to me, but I've not checked in detail